# Trouble mapping XML to a list of POJOs in Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to take XML that looks like something like the following:

```
<root:ElementName>
    <equipment:Equipment>
        <eqp:Name>Equipment 1</eqp:Name>
        <eqp:Type>A</eqp:Type>
    </equipment:Equipment>
    <equipment:Equipment>
        <eqp:Name>Equipment 2</eqp:Name>
        <eqp:Type>B</eqp:Type>
    </equipment:Equipment><equipment:Equipment>
        <eqp:Name>Equipment 3</eqp:Name>
        <eqp:Type>C</eqp:Type>
    </equipment:Equipment>
</root:ElementName>
```

And I want to map that into a list of "Equipment" POJOs. I'm using Jackson XML mapping and Lombok, so basically I've got this split into two classes right now, first the root object which should read in that `<root:ElementName>` and turn all the `<equipment:Equipment>` tags into a list of equipment objects:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root:ElementName")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EquipmentMidbCompositeResponse
{

    @JsonProperty("equipment")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "equipment:Equipment")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    List<Equipment> equipmentList;

}
```

And then the Equipment object itself:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Equipment
{
    @JsonCreator
    public  Equipment(String name){
    }

    @JsonProperty("EquipmentName")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "eqp:Name")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("EquipmentType")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "eqp:Type")
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String type;
}
```

At first I didn't have that constructor with @JsonCreator in the Equipment object and would get a "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value" error, and after some research added the constructor to get around that. With that I get past that error, but the list of Equipment objects that gets returned after mapping have all their fields set to null. What am I missing/doing wrong here when trying to map these XML properties?

Comment: XML tags are ignored in posts here (the editor supports a subset of HTML instead). So, I have edited your post to reveal them with backticks - please use the preview window when writing posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I figured out the issue, my approach with the @JsonCreator was the incorrect way to go for that error. Turns out all I had to do was an a @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false) annotation to my list item and everything went through just fine.